# Chrome extension to focus on omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to focus on the omnibox, either using the ExecuteScript or the Omnibox API? I don't think its possible but can anyone think of a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, currently not possible.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the ability to do this would really let us make some extensions more natural