# Chrome: how to remap Ctrl+D to focus on the address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

do you know any extension or whatever to remap the Ctrl+D to "fo"?

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt+D focuses the address bar in almost any application.

To remap see [chrome.experimental.keybinding](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.keybinding.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible as far as I know (unless a new API has been added since then): [Chrome extension to focus on omnibox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7295986/163956)